# Page Editor Mode - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sitecore

I am getting a really strange error currently for one sitecore user, randomly a server error appears - However, the user can refresh the page and the page loads without an error (according to the user). I'm not sure what this error would be relating to, would anyone have any input?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Sitecore.Data.Database.ApplySecurity(Item[] items) +112
>   Sitecore.Data.Database.SelectItems(String query) +252
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.OpenMyItems.GetHeader(CommandContext
>   context, String header) +188
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallButton(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +307
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +732
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext) +330
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
>   isContextual, String id) +204
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
>   isContextual) +242
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
>   isContextual) +442
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString
>   visibleStripList) +800
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString
>   visibleStripList) +215
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +610
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +149
>   Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl) +74
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderRibbon(Item
>   item) +603
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +1238
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +193    System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35    Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +337    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have recently upgraded your Sitecore instance, you can get this error at times, and the LinkDatabase can become corrupted.

Read this article for more information.
http://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/26/sitecore-linkdatabase-unrecognized-guid-format/

However, it is odd that is only one user. Please let us know what solves it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I shall look in to it